# csrfToken() is not working with html page?

Tags: api, security, token, csrf, csrf-token

I am having node js backened server and frontend is simple html file running as a spa server.

```html
 <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <form action="http://localhost:3000/entry" method="POST">
      <div>
        <label for="message">Enter a message</label>
        <input id="message" name="message" type="text" />
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken()}}" />
    </form>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What error are you facing ?

Comment: it is not generated in html page